# The problems with the multiple filter functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a code for filters of an image and I am having issues with my current code. When I change one of the sliders, the image turns out to be just white. I am not really sure what the problem is behind these codes, I have no idea how to fix this. I tried changing variables around but didn't seek any luck.

It should change the image just like an image filter will do.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

var slider1 = document.getElementById("slider1");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("slider2");
var slider3 = document.getElementById("slider3");
var slider4 = document.getElementById("slider4");
var slider5 = document.getElementById("slider5");
var slider6 = document.getElementById("slider6");
var slider7 = document.getElementById("slider7");

var sepia = slider1.value;
var blur = slider2.value;
var invert = slider3.value;
var contrast = slider4.value;
var opacity = slider5.value;
var grayscale = slider6.value;
var brightness = slider7.value;

slider1.addEventListener("input", function(){
    sepia = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "sepia(" + this.value + "%) blur("+blur+"px) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider2.addEventListener("input", function(){
    blur = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur(" + this.value + "px) sepia("+sepia+"%) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider3.addEventListener("input", function(){
    invert = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "invert(" + this.value + "%) sepia("+sepia+"%) blur("+blur+"px) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider4.addEventListener("input", function(){
    contrast = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "contrast(" + this.value + "%) sepia("+sepia+"%) blur("+blur+"px) invert("+invert+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider5.addEventListener("input", function(){
    opacity = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "opacity(" + this.value + "%) sepia("+sepia+"%) blur("+blur+"px) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider6.addEventListener("input", function(){
    grayscale = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "grayscale(" + this.value + "%) sepia("+sepia+"%) blur("+huerotate+"px) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) brightness("+brightness+")";
});

slider7.addEventListener("input", function(){
    brightness = this.value;
    img.style["-webkit-filter"] = "grayscale(" + this.value + "%) sepia("+sepia+"%) blur("+blur+"px) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%)";
});
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/591093476/bird.jpg">
<input type="range" id="slider1" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider2" value="4">
<input type="range" id="slider3" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider4" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider5" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider6" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider7" value="50">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brightness has no unit(%)

```
img.style["-webkit-filter"] ="sepia(" + this.value + "%) blur("+blur+"px) invert("+invert+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%) opacity("+opacity+"%) grayscale("+grayscale+"%) brightness("+brightness+"%)";
```

The following is the rewriting of the original post:

```js
// get reference
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var sliders = {
    sepia: document.getElementById('slider1'),
    blur: document.getElementById('slider2'),
    invert: document.getElementById('slider3'),
    contrast: document.getElementById('slider4'),
    opacity: document.getElementById('slider5'),
    grayscale: document.getElementById('slider6'),
    brightness: document.getElementById('slider7')
};
// set to correct values
sliders.sepia.value = 0;
sliders.blur.value = 0;
sliders.invert.value = 0;
sliders.contrast.value = 100;
sliders.opacity.value = 100;
sliders.grayscale.value = 0;
sliders.brightness.value = 100;

function render() {
    img.style['-webkit-filter'] =
        'sepia(' + sliders.sepia.value + '%)' +
        'blur(' + sliders.blur.value + 'px)' +
        'invert(' + sliders.invert.value + '%)' +
        'contrast(' + sliders.contrast.value + '%)' +
        'opacity(' + sliders.opacity.value + '%)' +
        'grayscale(' + sliders.grayscale.value + '%)' +
        'brightness(' + sliders.brightness.value + '%)';
}

// bind listeners
for (var filterName in sliders) {
    sliders[filterName].addEventListener('input', render);
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/591093476/bird.jpg">
<input type="range" id="slider1" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider2" value="4">
<input type="range" id="slider3" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider4" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider5" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider6" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider7" value="50">
```